# Eclipse Oxygen quits automatically on Ubuntu 14.04 with jvm exit code 1

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I have come across a problem with my latest eclipse oxygen on Ubuntu 14.04 (installed within VMware). Each time after being launched for several minutes and operated on, it crashes.

This is the error message that always pops up:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.7.0.20170620-1800/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133/eclipse_1624.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata cc0022
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

There is no .log file in .metadata folder the first time it crashes in a freshly-created workspace.

By entering in terminal `file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac`, the output is:

```
/etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java' 
/etc/alternatives/javac: symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac'
```

and `java -version` yields

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Also, in case it may be of any use, below is my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

I have tried a lot of methods online but none matches my case perfectly and none seems to be working.

My Eclipse was downloaded from the official site (the C/C++ package) and placed under /opt. Everything is 64-bit. I also tried deleting the eclipse package file and reinstall but failed many times with the same problem. (Not sure whether deleting the file means "uninstalling" it)

Hope someone could help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried opening a new workspace yet? If I saw this message, I would create a new workspace, *The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.*

Comment: Thanks @ThisClark, I have re-tried and have updated the problem. Turns out that the root of the problem should lie in something related to jvm. Any ideas?

Comment: I really have no idea. In such cases, I would try reinstalling everything. Sorry I can't be more helpful. Here's an install link for command line options: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse. In particular, this option addresses 14.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/677801/541721